# Pad trues in a binary matrix (more efficiently than with a binary dilation)

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image, mathematical-morphology

Problem statement:

I have a very large binary matrix, lets say with dimensions (1000000,500), for which I want to spread the existing trues along its columns.

More specifically, for each True in the matrix, I'd like to pad $N$ Trues along the column right after it.

One approach to solving this is with a binary_dilation from skimage or scipy.

For example, the following would pad two Trues after each True as desired.

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.rand(1000000,500)

t1=time.time()

#in this case N=2
s = np.array([[0],
              [0],
              [1],
              [1],
              [1]])
out = morphology.binary_dilation(a > 0.95,s)

t2=time.time()

print(t2 - t1) #9.127300500869751
```

However, I suspect there's some redundancy in the operation performed by the dilation, since it's designed to solve a far more general problem. Moreover, the dilation's time scales linearly when increasing the number of columns, so I think there's got to be a faster way.

Any ideas for a more efficient approach?

Alternatively, a similar problem which I'm also interested in is the following:
Given a binary matrix, fill Trues between two Trues a distance of at most $N$ rows from each other and at most a single column from each other (if they are in neighboring columns, fill the column of the first true: the one with a smaller row number). I have used skimage.morphology.remove_small_holes iteratively over the columns, to partly solve this, but it doesn't handle neighboring columns, and again I think there's a more efficient approach.

**Important context:**

My goal here is to help connect nearby regions before labeling them with scipy.ndiamge.label or skimage.measure.label. Therefore, both the problems above are equivalent, since after labeling I can conjunct with the original binary matrix (the one before the padding) to remove all the trues that were not originally there.

Comment: Try the `dip.Dilation` function in DIPlib, it’s a lot faster than scikit-image (and time should be independent of the N). https://diplib.org

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks. It appears to be roughly twice as fast with the line dilation.

Comment: The "rectangular" dilation is always the fastest. Not sure how the line dilation is implemented when the line is horizontal or vertical, it might be the same, it might be slower.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Tried both and for me line was faster (in this special case of vertical). Btw I can’t yet upvote but thanks again!